# C++ variadic template with tuple as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to have something like this (warning: invalid code):

```
template<std::tuple<typename T, typename... Args>>
class nDimensionalPoint
```

This way, I could work with `n`-dimensional points one dimension at a time.
Of course, I could avoid the `std::tuple` part by declaring
`template<typename T, typename... Args>` and simply passing
the coordinates in each dimension in a vector of its own,
but that creates the following difficulty: One needs to somehow bind together
the coordinates hidden in `args...`. Therefore, I would like a cleaner way
of making it explicit that the underlying type is variadic tuple.
How this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might declare it as partial specialization as

```
template<typename>
class nDimensionalPoint;
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class nDimensionalPoint<std::tuple<T, Args...>> {};
```

then use it like

```
nDimensionalPoint<std::tuple<int, char>> dp ...;
```